# How to resolve an 'undefined variable' issue in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am unable to find a solution to this problem I have depicted below. It shows that the variables $fName and other variable like $MNane are undefined as well as other variable like $fnameerr and so on, even though I have defined them later in my php script.

I am trying to a validated registration form. I have never come across this issue as previously this code has worked perfectly many times before. I do not have much knowledge about this language.

HTML code:

```
   <!-- Header -->
  <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="img-fluid mb-5 d-block mx-auto" src="img/profile.png" 
  alt="">
    <h1 class="text-uppercase mb-0">SOCIETY-123</h1>
    <hr class="star-light">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light mb-0">Maintain your house on Rent - Sell 
  house - Manage the Society</h2>
   </div>
   </header>
<div>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>">  
    <center><h1 class="text-uppercase mb-0">Registration</h1></center>
    <hr class="star-dark mb-5">
    <table class="registration1">    
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-right: 60px;">Firstname:<input type="text" name="FName" placeholder=" Firstname" value="<?php echo $FName;?>"><span><?php echo $FNameerr;?></span></td> 
            <td style="padding-right: 60px;">Middlename:<input type="text" name="MName" placeholder=" Middlename" value="<?php echo $MName;?>"><span><?php echo $MNameerr;?></span></td>
            <td style="padding-right: 60px;">Lastname:<input type="text" name="LName" placeholder=" Lastname" value="<?php echo $LName;?>"><span><?php echo $LNameerr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="padding-top: 30px;">
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">Gender: Male<input type="radio" name="Gender" <?php if(isset($Gender) && $Gender == "male") echo checked;?> value="male"></td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">Female<input type="radio" name="Gender"<?php if(isset($Gender) && $Gender == "female") echo checked;?> value="female"></td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">other<input type="radio" name="Gender"<?php if(isset($Gender) && $Gender == "other") echo checked;?> value="other"><span><?php echo $Gendererr;?></span></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">Address: <input type="text" name="add" placeholder="Type your address here" size="30" value="<?php echo $add;?>"><span><?php echo $adderr;?></span></td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">Occupation<input type="text" name="occu" placeholder=" occupation" value="<?php echo $occu;?>"><span><?php echo $occuerr;?></span></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">Residence type: self owned<input type="radio" name="Resi"<?php if(isset($Resi) && $Resi == "selfowned") echo checked;?> value="selfowned"></td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;"> Rented<input type="radio" name="Resi"<?php if(isset($resi) && $Resi == "rented") echo checked;?> value="rented"><span><?php echo $Resierr;?></span></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">E-mail id:<input type="text" name="eid" placeholder=" e-mail id" value="<?php echo $eid;?>"><span><?php echo $eiderr;?></span></td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px;">password:<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder=" password" value="<?php echo $pass;?>"><span><?php echo $passerr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
  <?php
  $FName = $MName = $LName = $Gender = $add = $occu = $Resi = $eid = $pass = 
"";
 $FNameerr = $MNameerr = $LNameerr = $Gendererr = $adderr = $occuerr = $Resierr = $eiderr = $passerr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["FName"])){
        $FNameerr = "firstname is required";
    }
    else{
        $FName = test_input($_POST["FName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/",$FName)){
            $FNameerr = "Only letter and whitespaces allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["MName"])){
        $MNameerr = "middlename is required";
    }
    else{
        $MName = test_input($_POST["MName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/",$MName)){
            $MNameerr = "Only letter and whitespaces allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["LName"])){
        $LNameerr = "lastname is required";
    }
    else{
        $LName = test_input($_POST["LName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/",$LName)){
            $LNameerr = "Only letter and whitespaces allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["Gender"])){
        $Gendererr = "choosing a gender is required";
    }
    else{
        $Gender = test_input($_POST["Gender"]);

    }


    if (empty($_POST["add"])){
        $adderr = "choosing a gender is required";
    }
    else{
        $add = test_input($_POST["add"]);

    }

if (empty($_POST["occu"])){
        $occuerr = "middlename is required";
    }
    else{
        $occu = test_input($_POST["occu"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/",$occu)){
            $occuerr = "Only letter and whitespaces allowed";
        }
    }

  if (empty($_POST["Resi"])){
        $Resierr = "choosing a gender is required";
    }
    else{
        $Resi = test_input($_POST["Resi"]);

    }

 if (empty($_POST["eid"])){
     $eiderr = "email id is required";
    }
     else{
         $eid = test_input($_POST["eid"]);
    if (!filter_var($eid, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $eidErr = "Invalid email format"; 
       } 
    }

    }

  function test_input($data){

   $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;


}    



?>


 here is my entire block of code
```

Though I have define the variables over here in the php script

Comment: Is your php code executed before your HTML ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @NickParsons no

Comment: @NickParsons do you have a solution???

Comment: You need to execute your php code before your HTML, because if it isn't executed before then your HTML (php within it) won't know what any of your variables are

Comment: The error pretty much sums it up: you are trying to use a variable, for example by doing `echo $FName;` before you have declared it, `$FName = "";

Comment: @NickParsons  thank you your tip helped but now i have another issue that when i click on the submit button the validations dont work.any other tips???

Comment: @nilesh yes, you need to change your submit button to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" value="submit">` (notice the change in the type) and remove `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this, I hope it will work**

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding-right: 60px;">Firstname:<input type="text" 
    name="FName" placeholder=" Firstname" value="<?= (!empty($FName)) ? $FName : "" ?>">
```